# iOS compatible facebook video link

Tags: ios, facebook, flash, video

I am trying to link to a specific video from facebook directly in iOS.
There are apps in AppStore that do exactly that (feks iLoaderLite).

I have the id of the video, and when i use the link on the mac, the video opens (using flash i suppose).

The link is "http://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=1432879026926621".

When I use the same link in a webView, the webView responds by requiring flash, which of course is not available for the iOS.

If I use MPMoviePlayer, nothing is loaded and I have a black screen since it cannot decode the flash video.

How do can I link to a Facebook video in iOS?

Anybody has an idea???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Using the Graph Api explorer tool for facebook (google it), you can enter the video id, and search for the video. If you output "source" you get a link with the video source in mp4. You can add parameters, and search for other stuff too.